# Website changes according to hours of the day

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know if there's a way of having a website that changes with the hours of the day. Example: Let's say we have 3 images (*image1.png*, *image2.png* and *image3.png*). Each image represents a show of a TV Station. What I would like is to setup a webpage that displays the images in this way:

• From 7am to 10 am - Show "image1.png"
• From 10:01 am to 2pm - Show "image2.png"
• From 2:01pm to 8pm - Show "image3.png"

Thank you in  advance.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  What webserver? Do you know how to write javascript?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: look into the switch() statement combined with the time on the client.

Comment: Dear @NathanielJohnson, unfortunantly I don't know how to write js. I was thinking in hosting that page on a directory on my website and then display the page in an iOS app through UIWebView. I don't know if this is useful. Thanks

Comment: @ChrisHardie I only tried to look if I could do it with xml. I have not written any code.

Comment: If you do it in javascript, then the website will change depending on the client's machine hour.  Better to do this server side...

Comment: Do timezones matter? would you want this to run solely on EST or PST...etc?

Comment: @bastos.sergio Not necessarily... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

Comment: Can't see how that would work... You would still need a way to define the server's timezone in javascript...

Answer (score 1):

Easily achievable in Javascript (or PHP if you know it). Let's take for example JavaScript, however:

```
document.body.onload = function()
{
     var rightNow = new Date();
     var hour = rightNow.getHours();
     var img = document.getElementById("myimageid");
     if(7<hour<9) //If it's between 7 AM and 9:59 AM
     {
         img.src = "image1.png";
     }
     else if(10<hour<13) //If it's between 10 AM and 1:59 PM
     {
         img.src = "image2.png";
     }
     else if(14<hour<19) //If it's between 2 PM and 7:59 PM
     {
         img.src = "image3.png";
     }
}
```

Haven't tested this, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It is a server side scenario. You have tagged the question with 'javascript', which is a client side script. It will always return the time on "User's PC". The facility you are trying to embed should be implemented in your server side script. Which script are you using PHP/ASP ?

```
<?php 

switch (TRUE){ 
$hour = date('H');
case ($hour 7 > 10): 
$show = '<img src="/images/image1.gif">'; 
break; 

default: 
$show = '<img src="/images/image2.gif">'; 
break; 
} 

echo "$show"; 
?>
```

You can add more 'cases' as per your need! 
Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Not necessarily a server side scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var dt = new Date();
    var h = dt.getHours() + 1;
    if (h >=7 && h < 10) {
        //set bg 1
    } else if (h >= 10 && h < 2) {
        //set bg 2
    } else if (h >= 2 && h < 8) {
        //set bg 3
    } else {
        //set def bg
    }
```